# How to download College Scorecard raw data

Tags: data-request, data.gov, collegescorecard

How can I download the raw data for the College Scorecard application? Specifically I am interested in cost of attendance information. When I visited the link to download a zip file [from this page](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/college-scorecard/resource/b8f3d10b-0974-40db-b5fa-3c87ecae516b), I received a 404 error. I reported the error on Data.gov, but I am hoping others know of a way to get that information.

I work for a scholarship/college access organization and college cost of attendance is necessary in determining how much to award a student. It would be impracticable and a waste of resource to manually gather this information for every single college when it appears to be open source and available through College Scorecard.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try going to the canonical source of the data; [data.gov](https://www.data.gov/) is a metadata portal first and foremost. Inevitably, there will be somethings lost in translation, most likely because of linkrot.

data.gov's catalog points to datasets created by 3rd party canonical authors/sources; these 3rd parties (in this context, almost entirely U.S. federal government agencies) can be found/tracked by viewing the breadcrumbs and/or the logo in the content document of the dataset.

For example, the [College Scorecard dataset document on data.gov](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/college-scorecard) denotes the owner of the dataset in a number of places, including: breadcrumbs ("Department of Education"), and in agency/department/organization logo in the right column of the document. The following image is a screenshot of this datasets document on data.gov, showing these examples:[image: Screenshot of a data.gov dataset document; The dataset's owner is denoted in the document's breadcrumbs ('Department of Education'), as well as by the ed.gov logo on the right hand side.]

The correct answer to 'How to download College Scorecard raw data' in this context then, is [to download it from the source](https://ed-public-download.app.cloud.gov/downloads/CollegeScorecard_Raw_Data.zip).

The difference between the two is data.gov points to the `.app` subdomain, while College Scorecard points to the `.apps` subdomain.

[College Scorecard Data (Canonical Source)](https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/) is where I found the raw data link, and there's other information there regarding the dataset as well.

The initial solution, and always the immediate goto once something goes missing from the web, is the Wayback Machine. Wayback has a few versions, here is one from 2017-02, [available here](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20170211004017/https://ed-public-download.apps.cloud.gov/downloads/CollegeScorecard_Raw_Data.zip)

Answer (score 1):

Brittany, I've just downloaded the data from [here](https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/) and it worked.